# Is currency conversion and foreign transaction fee inevitable when purchasing a service from a country different from a credit card company?

Tags: credit-card, foreign-exchange, debit-card, paypal

I purchased plane tickets at Kuwait Airways website, for a trip originated from US with a transition/overlay at Kuwait, by using Fidelity Rewards Credit Card, a credit card issued in US.
My credit card account shows not just the transaction, but also a second one with 1% of the ticket price, labeled as  FRGN TRANS FEE and charged by Kuwait Airways if I am not mistaken.

```
DESCRIPTION: Frgn Trans Fee-Kuwait Ai2292113807162 Ci

TYPE: FRGN TRANS FEE

Merchant details
CATEGORY: KUWAIT AIRWAYS
METHOD: Manually Entered
```

I remember seeing the price in US dollars and not seeing any currency conversion or foreign transaction fee,  when placing the order directly at the airline website. My credit card company replied to me:

> As disclosed in your Cardmember Agreement, if you use your card for
> retail purchases at foreign merchants or for cash withdrawals from
> foreign ATMs, your foreign currency transaction will be converted to
> U.S. dollars, and you will be assessed a foreign transaction fee. The
> fee is 1% of each U.S. dollar amount. This fee applies when the
> merchant is located in a country other than the United States, even on
> transactions submitted to us in U.S. dollars.

> The merchant's business name listed with Visa is Kuwait Airlines.

When using a credit card to make a purchase of a service of a merchant located in a country different from US where the credit card company is located,

- Does it matter to the following questions whether the merchant lists their service in US dollars or a different currency on their website?
- is there always currency conversion?
- is a foreign transaction fee inevitable, regardless of its percentage of the service price (and regardless of whether the credit card company or the merchant want to charge any at all i.e. whether the percentage is 0%)?
- who charges for the foreign transaction fee, the merchant, or the credit card company?
- Is it possible to know about the amount of foreign transaction fee when placing an order with a merchant outside the country of the credit card company?
- Is it possible to avoid foreign transaction fee using a different payment method from credit card? For example, debit card, Paypal?

Thanks.

Comment: No.  Some cards explicitly have zero foreign transaction fee.  You just have to find one and sign up for it **IF** you make enough  foreign transactions to make it worth the hassle.  For example, I got a Bank of America card for my kids to use when they went to Europe .  But I just made a foreign purchase on my regular card because it was convenient.  The ForEx fee is the cost of that convenience.

Comment: What is the convenience when you just made a foreign purchase on your regular card?

Comment: As for the amount… you posted the card member agreement; it said 1%.vAnd as for who charges it: the bank, of course, since they’re the ones doing the work and taking the risk.

Comment: Tim, obviously the convenience is in not having to convert your currency to the foreign currency.

Comment: Lots and lots of effort goes on behind the scenes to make your life easy.

Comment: What convenience does your regular card provide over the credit cards of your kids, which makes paying foreign transaction fees worthwhile?

Comment: @Tim generally cards that have no foreign transaction fees will make the money in different ways. Many would require membership fees one way or another, or require some level of credit worthiness that not everyone has (i.e.: expecting you to spend more)

Comment: Related: [How can I know before paying whether the payment will incur foreign transaction fees?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/152375/5656);  [What's the cheapest way of paying by card abroad?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/175942/1810)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt indeed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know before paying whether the payment will incur foreign transaction fees?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152375/how-can-i-know-before-paying-whether-the-payment-will-incur-foreign-transaction)

Comment: @keshlam my question is different. The price was listed in US dollars by the airline, so I was not aware of any foreign transaction fee, and was surprised to see it.

Comment: Ask the airline. They may have converted the price as a convenience for you. But they can't tell you how much your bank is going to charge for currency conversion fees, so unless they have a US affiliate, have you pay there, and eat the conversion costs themselves the best they can do is give you the equivalent without that cost.  Given all the other hidden fees that often find their way into airfare, I don't think this should be considered overly surprising.

Comment: "What convenience does your regular card provide over the credit cards of your kids, which makes paying foreign transaction fees worthwhile?" 1.5% cash back on every US dollar-denominated purchase (which is 99.999% of all my purchases when not on a foreign vacation).

Comment: There are also a couple of different ways foreign transaction fees are charged. With my Bank of America cards, they charge a foreign transaction fee based on where the transaction takes place, even if the charge is in USD. With my citibank cards, they only charge a foreign transaction fee if the charge was in something other than USD. And I have other cards that don't charge a foreign transaction fee regardless of where the charge is or in what currency (although I'd guess they make up for it by giving me a poor exchange rate).

Comment: @Tim The convenience is you not having to drive to the airport to go to the Kuwait Airlines ticket counter with a pile of cash.

Comment: Related: [Are there any credit cards with no foreign transaction fee for international travel?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/3552/5656)

Comment: Related: [Why do the banks charge a foreign transaction fee?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/35565/5656)

Answer (score 8):

> who charges for the foreign transaction fee, the merchant, or the credit card company?

Foreign transaction fees are charged by your credit card issuer, not by the merchant. Not every credit card has foreign transaction fees, credit cards specifically geared towards travelers (e.g.: many airline branded, especially high-tier, or high-tier brands like Sapphire from Chase or Premier from Citi, or even the Costco card) do not charge foreign transaction fees.

Worth mentioning that the *"foreign"* in the *"**foreign** transaction fee"* relates to the merchant, not the currency.

> Is it possible to know about the amount of foreign transaction fee when placing an order with a merchant outside the country of the credit card company?

Absolutely. It should be detailed in your credit card terms and conditions. In the US it must be explicitly stated in the term sheet before you sign up for the card.

> is there always currency conversion?

Merchants operating in a different country operate in the currency of that country. So if you transact with such a merchant there's bound to be a conversion somewhere.

Currency conversion is a separate issue, and different banks and merchants have different rates. Usually doing conversion through your credit card would yield best results (especially higher-tier/traveler brands), but check and confirm. Different cards would have different rates, some better for one currency, others may be better for another. Shop around. From my experience, allowing the merchant to do the conversion would yield the absolute worst (by far) rate for you since it gives the merchant an opportunity to make more money off of you. Merchants listing prices in foreign currency would usually assume their own conversion rate.

> Is it possible to avoid foreign transaction fee using a different payment method from credit card? For example, debit card, Paypal?

Shop around for credit cards without foreign transaction fees, there are a lot. Specifics depend on your country, I mentioned some US-centric examples above.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "Merchants operating in a different country operate in the currency of that country. So if you transact with such a merchant there's bound to be a conversion somewhere." The ticket price was listed in US dollars on the airline website, and therefore no ambiguity of currency conversion rate is involved. (2) Does whether the merchant lists their service in US dollars or a different currency on their website matter to the applicability/ existence of  foreign transaction fee?

Comment: @Tim (1) it's up to the merchant to decide in what currency/currencies to charge. (2) no. The "*foreign*" in the *"**foreign** transaction fee*" relates to the merchant, not the currency.

Comment: Thanks. (1) I am asking about foreign transaction fee, not currency conversion rate. The airline already provided the price in US dollars, and I found them by comparing on Expedia, so I assumed the tickets were sold in US dollars, and never thought about how the airline determined the price in US dollars.

Comment: @Tim again, the *foreign* in *foreign transaction* relates to the merchant, not the currency. The conversion costs are already reflected in the USD price you got. The merchant charged you in USD, but their home country uses a different currency, so their operational currency is different. They did the USD->whatever conversion for you themselves and charged you for that, as part of the USD price you paid. But for the *foreign transaction* fee it doesn't matter - the merchant is foreign.

Comment: Note that just about every detail of this topic depends on where you're based, and potentially on the details of your card agreement. It may be that U.S. card issuers universally charge for foreign _merchant_ transactions regardless of currency, but that can be different elsewhere. For example, in Israel, the fee is assessed for the currency conversion specifically, so there's never any additional charge in the case of a foreign merchant that posts a charge in ILS.

Comment: (Also, while it's not common, if you have e.g. dollars in your bank account, your card can be set up to charge dollar transactions to there, sans conversion)

Comment: @Micha in Israel you need to choose which currency is the "main" one (you can choose EUR, USD, and maybe GBP - don't remember), and every other currency will be first converted to that, and then to your ILS. You may even pay conversion fees for local merchants if they charge you in the wrong currency. So a different kind of fun, but still fun. That said, Israel is a tiny place and it's local market is saturated, so charging for a transaction with every merchant is risky. For US, UK and European countries - you're more likely to get charged for merchant than for currency.

Comment: @littleadv It depends on the currency in question. Assuming the underlying bank account is a shekel account, if the currency is one of the 14 that has a representative rate set by the BoI (https://www.boi.org.il/en/economic-roles/financial-markets/exchange-rates/) then the companies must by law use that rate and convert directly to shekels. If not, then Cal, Amex, and Isracard convert the amount to USD using the applicable network's rates (Visa/MC/Amex), and then to shekels using the USD BoI rate. The one outlier is Max, which uses USD for Visa and EUR for MC. They don't let you choose AFAIK.

Comment: And like I said in my first comment, the fee is for the conversion, never the merchant, so if a local merchant charges you in USD you're paying the fee, though that's definitely not a common thing at all. Maybe in the tourism/travel sector. And yeah, my point was just that it depends on the specific case - I would be surprised if we were unique globally in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

The listed currency only sometimes matters. If you pay in your local currency, either the merchant will charge you from a local (to you) subsidiary - in which case there’s no foreign transaction fee - or from their normal account but in your currency, in which case you’ll pay the fee *and* get the merchant’s usually-poor exchange rate.

There is always a currency conversion when paying in a foreign currency; that’s tautological. Not all banks charge such a fee, but most do, and those charges will be listed in your account agreement. To the extent that the merchant charges any fees, those will be included in the total you directly pay, not added on later.

Revolut is a common service used by people trying to avoid foreign transaction fees (and poor exchange rates). There are others as well. Paypal will not help you avoid this fee, and debit card foreign transaction fees are often higher than credit card fees.

Comment: thanks. (1) "There is always a currency conversion when paying in a foreign currency". Does my case sound like that I pay the plane tickets in a foreign currency, when the airline lists the prices in US dollars on their website?

Comment: (2) " If you pay in your local currency, either the merchant will charge you from a local (to you) subsidiary - in which case there’s no foreign transaction fee - or from their normal account but in your currency, in which case you’ll pay the fee and get the merchant’s usually-poor exchange rate."  What does "a local subsidiary" mean? Kuwait Airways has an office in NYC, and does that count as a subsidiary local to US? What does "their normal account" mean?

Comment: @Tim Again, the currency doesn't matter; the location of the merchant account (the bank account to which credit card payments are eventually deposited) matters. And Kuwait Airways having an office in NYC isn't strong evidence of where their merchant account is. This is not information that is readily available, I'm afraid.

Comment: [Why are foreign transaction fees with debit cards often higher than foreign transaction fees with credit cards?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155271/5656)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142915/discussion-on-answer-by-sneftel-is-currency-conversion-and-foreign-transaction-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.