# Why are foreign transaction fees with debit cards often higher than foreign transaction fees with credit cards?

Tags: credit-card, international, fees, debit-card

I read in this [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155237/5656) by [Sneftel](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/50628/sneftel):

> Debit card foreign transaction fees are often higher than credit card fees.

I've noticed that too with cards issued in the US. Why are foreign transaction fees with debit cards often higher than foreign transaction fees with credit cards?

Comment: You are asking why the poster Sneftel posted something? Why don't you ask the poster directly?

Comment: @littleadv comments aren't made to last.

Comment: Why do you want your personal discussion with someone else to last on this public forum? The question is not relevant to anyone but you. Who cares about random speculation between two random people on the internet? Neither the question nor the answer are factual or useful to anyone or anything other than satisfying your personal curiosity triggered by someone's unsubstantiated claim.

Comment: @littleadv nothing is personal in this question.

Comment: It starts with "**I**".

Comment: @littleadv "Why are foreign transaction fees with debit cards often higher than foreign transaction fees with credit cards?"

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to remove any mention of yourself or the other poster, but then you'll just be repeating a baseless claim asking for someone to substantiate it for you.

Comment: @littleadv I prefer to respect the license of the content.

Comment: Ask the bank, but the answer probably boils down to "credit cards produce income which offsets the fees."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the consensus is that foreign transaction fees with debit cards often higher than foreign transaction fees with credit cards because credit cards are more profitable to the issuer.

From [Reddit](https://redd.it/113bjp8) user [Mysunsai](https://www.reddit.com/user/Mysunsai):

> Because credit cards are more profitable due to higher merchant processing fees. Same reason that credit cards in the US offer reward points.

From SE:

> the answer probably boils down to "credit cards produce income which offsets the fees.[keshlam](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/12439/keshlam) [39 mins ago](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155271/why-are-foreign-transaction-fees-with-debit-cards-often-higher-than-foreign-tran?noredirect=1#comment317516_155271)

Comment: Quoting random people from various online forums isn't exactly a high quality answer. Are there any sources you can include to back up these claims? As an aside, the constant posting of frivolous questions and self-answers looks a lot like karma farming... Congrats on breaking the 10k threshold.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD The vast majorities of answers on stack exchange don't cite any references. The questions are not frivolous to me and self-answers are welcome on Stack Exchange.